# Active record group by two separate values

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a table called `Documents` that looks (in part) as below. There is a document ID, a file type, and a user_id.

```
id     type  user_id
1      PDF    1 
2      PDF    1 
3      PDF    2 
4      PDF    3 
5      JPG    1 
6      JPG    3 
7      JPG    3 
8      JPG    3 
9      JPG    1
10     PNG    2 
11     PNG    2
```

What I am trying to do is count how many users have uploaded each different file type. So given the data above... I would like something along the lines of:

```
{"PDF" => 3, "JPG" => 2, "PNG" => 1}
```

Meaning 3 **different** users have uploaded PDFs, 2 **different** users have uploaded JPGs, etc.

I tried doing `Document.group(:user_id).group(:type).count` but that gave me a huge hash of every `user_id`/`type` combo with a count...

Comment: @lad2025 add that as an answer and I'll mark it as the solution. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
Document.select('distinct user_id').group(:type).count
```

Answer (score 3):

Using pure SQL:

```
SELECT type, COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS cnt 
FROM Documents 
GROUP BY type;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/WDTXJQ4175)**</kbd>

Comment: This is the way to do it in SQL.